# How do I select a random word within a cell?

Tags: random, google-sheets

I want randomly to select a word from a cell that is generated by a form field using the "paragraph" answer option.

Comment: I guess you'll want to use the function randbetween. (cf. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093507) The upper bound will be the character count of the cell value, use the resulting value to get the n-th letter.

Comment: so say column C has anywhere from 2 to 50 words and I want one of those words in column D for each of those rows, each one being random... I start here =RANDBETWEEN(C2:C50) but I am getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one formula:

```
=index(split(A1," "),randbetween(1,1+len(A1)-len(substitute(A1," ",""))))
```

Does not remove punctuation.

Anchor the `1`s in `A1`s (ie > `A$1`s) and can be copied down to suit (for different choices from the same cell).

Comment: holy $it thanks! I feel guilty now about that being a "homework" question but I literally cut and pasted your formula and it worked exactly right! that has never happened before in the history of the internet

Comment: now I am getting greedy, but is there any way to get the formula to know what row it is in automatically? If I want to past the formula into the entire row and not have to edit the 3 references to the row number each time?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to get a random word from a string in cell `A1`:

- Get word count:
  `A2 =if(A1="","",counta(split(A1," ")))`
- Get random value between 1 and word count:
  `A3 =randbetween(1,A2)`
- Get the random word using the random value:
  `A4 =index(split(A1, " "),A3)`